# При использовании нескольких join, начинают дублироваться данные

Tags: mysql, sql

При использовании нескольких join, начинают дублироваться данные.
Такой запрос вроде отрабатывает нормально:

```
select f.*, 
Group_concat(cc.country SEPARATOR ', ')  AS countries
from films f 
inner join connections_countries cc on cc.film = f.id_film
where f.id_film =1;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если присоединить еще одну таблицу, то данные в некоторых столбцах начинают дублироваться. См столбец countries.

```
select f.*, 
     Group_concat(nf.name_film SEPARATOR '/') AS name_film,
     Group_concat(cc.country SEPARATOR ', ')  AS countries
from films f 
inner join names_film nf on nf.id_film = f.id_film 
inner join connections_countries cc on cc.film = f.id_film
where f.id_film =1;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать нормально?
[source](https://github.com/Astrgan/ParserFilms/blob/master/src/createDB.sql)

Comment: покажите данные из `connections_countries` для id_film=1

Comment: если в *связанной* таблице для данной строки несколько строк, то это именно так как и должно работать, в этом случае если вы хотите получить из связанной таблице одно строку, то должны это явно выразить в запросе к бд

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, select * from connections_countries where connections_countries.film = 1; - |             1 |    1 | США     |

Comment: *Group_concat( **DISTINCT** cc.country SEPARATOR ', ')  AS countries*

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis, вот скрин: http://rlu.ru/2oJ6Q

Comment: @astrgan уже увидел, что проблема в `names_film`, т.к. название в двух вариантах. используйте вариант Akina.

Comment: @Akina помогло, спасибо :)

Comment: Как уже написали выше, **DISTINCT** поможет, но, лучше разобраться в самих данных. Возможно, стоит построить запрос по-другому - чтобы не было дубликатов в ответе (если возможно, конечно). Если таблицы меленькие, то разницы в скорости не будет, но на больших объёмах это будет ощутимо.

Но, я бы хотел сказать на счёт **GROUP_CONCAT**. Помните, что есть ограничение на длину возвращаемого значения - переменная **group_concat_max_len**. При достижении этого лимита, строка будет обрезана.

Comment: @Vitaly спасибо за информацию. В GROUP_CONCAT вроде не должны будут попадать слишком длинные строки. С запросом тоже хочется разобраться до конца, но пока даже не знаю в какую сторону думать. Недавно занялся запросами сложнее "select * from table".

Comment: @Vitaly *лучше разобраться в самих данных* Я бы сказал "разобраться в идеологии". Если дубликаты гарантированно незначимы - DISTINCT достаточен. А вот если нет (как вариант - иногда значимы), то именно от идеологии и следует плясать. Например, вязать в подзапросе две таблицы, там группировать, а потом в основном запросе к результату привязывать третью таблицу. Но это уже совсем другая история...

Comment: @Akina, полностью с вами согласен, если речь идёт про только разрабатываемую систему - тут нужно сразу с умом разработать архитектуру БД, чтобы избавить себя или тех кто будет потом поддерживать систему от головной боли в будущем. Но в уже работающей годами системе не всегда можно такое сделать. Максимум - только запросами.

Comment: А почему появляются дубликаты? Если я добавлю еще один join, то без DISTINCT дубликатов будет еще больше.

Comment: @astrgan из-за связей один-ко-многим. если join'ить несколько ко подобных таблиц, у которых заданы отношения по ключам один-ко-многим, то появляются дубликаты. Если брать всю результирующую строку целиком, то они будут уникальными (если в таблицах значения уникальны), но в разрезе только нужных полей, будут дубликаты. Тут, либо, добавлять условия для фильтрации записей, либо делать EXISTS. Но как писал Akina, лучше пересмотреть всю структуру хранения (если система только разрабатывается).

Comment: @astrgan Если, всё же, нужны JOIN и нужно избавиться от дубликатов, то можно делать подзапросы в самих JOIN `(... JOIN (SELECT ...) join_table ON join_table.key = main_table.key)`. Вариант, конечно, тоже не супер.